# Com criar um programa que leia 10 números e escreva o menor e maior valor lido (Python)?

Tags: python, for, while

Estou com uma certa dificuldade nesse exercício.
Aqui está meu código:

```
python
num = float(input('Digite o 1 numero: '))

guarda_maior = num
guarda_menor = num

for n in range(1, 10):

    num = float(input(f'Digite o valor de {n}: '))

    if num > guarda_maior:

        num = guarda_maior

    elif num < guarda_menor:

        num = guarda_menor

print(f'{guarda_maior}, {guarda_menor}')
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar.
Grato.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

O problema estava no fato de que o num estava recebendo a var ao invés da var estar recebendo o num

```
if num > guarda_maior:

        guarda_maior = num #troquei a ordem, agora guarda_maior recebera num ao inves de num receber guarda_maior

    elif num < guarda_menor:

        guarda_menor = num #troquei a ordem, agora guarda_menor recebera num ao inves de num receber guarda_menor

print(f'{guarda_maior}, {guarda_menor}')
```

Dessa forma acredito que será resolvido.

Comment: Nossa, tava tentando monte de coisa hahahaha.

Comment: Pequena falta de atenção...

Comment: Muito obrigado, João.

Comment: De nada, Douglas